# Awk if else with conditions

Tags: for-loop, awk

I am trying to make a script (and a loop) to extract matching lines to print them into a new file. There are 2 conditions: 1st is that I need to print the value of the 2nd and 4th columns of the map file if the 2nd column of the map file matches with the 4th column of the test file. The 2nd condition is that when there is no match, I want to print the value in the 2nd column of the test file and a zero in the second column.

My test file is made this way:

```
8   8:190568    0   190568  
8   8:194947    0   194947  
8   8:197042    0   197042  
8   8:212894    0   212894
```

My map file is made this way:

```
8   190568  0.431475    0.009489
8   194947  0.434984    0.009707
8   19056880    0.395066    112.871160
8   101908687   0.643861    112.872348
```

1st attempt:

```
for chr in {21..22}; 
do
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]; next} {if ($4 in a) print $2, $4 in a; else print $2, $4 == "0"}' map_chr$chr.txt test_chr$chr.bim > position.$chr;
done
```

Result:

```
8:190568 1
8:194947 1
8:197042 0
8:212894 0
```

My second script is:

```
for chr in {21..22}; do
    awk 'NR == FNR { ++a[$4]; next }
      $4 in a { print a[$2], $4; ++found[$2] }
      END { for(k in a) if (!found[k]) print a[k], 0 }' \
         "test_chr$chr.bim"  "map_chr$chr.txt" >> "position.$chr"
done
```

And the result is:

```
1 0
1 0
1 0
1 0
```

The result I need is:

```
8:190568 0.009489
8:194947 0.009707
8:197042 0
8:212894 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk 'FNR==NR {map[$2]=$4; next} {print $4, map[$4]+0}' mapfile testfile

190568 0.009489
194947 0.009707
197042 0
212894 0
```

This awk command processes `mapfile` first and stores `$2` as key with `$4` as a value in an associative array named as `map`.
Later when it processes `testfile` in 2nd block we print `$4` from 2nd file with the stored value in `map` using key as `$4`. We add `0` in stored value to make sure that we get `0` when `$4` is not present in `map`.

Comment: It worked perfectly! Can't believe I was struggling for so long and it wasn't extremely different from what I was trying in the first place. If you have time could you explain how it works?

Comment: I have added some explanation in my answer.